# How can I build a large version of the info-button on iOS?

Tags: ios, uibutton

For my next iOS app, I'd like to include a button to access an info screen - the typical use case for the infoButton. However I'd like to have it displayed larger than its stock size. Is there a way to do that using standard iOS icons or do I have to roll my own?

(Please note that I'm not interested in increasing the tap area, the "i" should also be larger.)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily just find some art that is a bigger 'i' and use it as a custom button but I don't think you can adjust the button from Apple.